# Large html string append using jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I want to append html inside an empty div:

```
<div id="admin_chatRoom">

</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
var chatBox = '<div class = "msg_box admin-msg-box" style = "right:55px;" >' +
                        '< div class = "msg_head " >' +
                        '<a onclick="if (confirm(&quot; Are you sure to active this Chat? &quot; )) { return true; } return false;"'+
                            'href="'+$("#webroot").text()+'/chats/activate/'+'10'+'" title="delete">'+
                            '<span class="fa fa-minus-square"></span>'+
                         '</a>'+                          
                        '&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
                        '< /div>' +
                        '< div class = "msg_wrap" >' +
                        '< div class = "msg_body" >' +
                        '< div class = "msg_push" > < /div>' +
                        '< /div>' +
                        '< div class = "msg_footer" > < textarea class = "msg_input" rows = "4" > < /textarea></div >' +
                        '< /div>' +
                        '< /div>';
                   $('#admin_chatRoom').append(chatBox);
               });
```

It should create chat box dynamically. But it just print out all html content as normal string. Whats wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your html formatting, the closing tags are not properly formatted... there is a space between `<` and `/`

```js
var chatBox = '<div class = "msg_box admin-msg-box" style = "right:55px;" >' +
  '<div class = "msg_head " >' +
  '<a onclick="if (confirm(&quot; Are you sure to active this Chat? &quot; )) { return true; } return false;"' +
  'href="' + $("#webroot").text() + '/chats/activate/' + '10' + '" title="delete">' +
  '<span class="fa fa-minus-square"></span>' +
  '</a>' +
  '&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="msg_wrap" >' +
  '<div class="msg_body" >' +
  '<div class="msg_push" ></div>' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="msg_footer" > <textarea class = "msg_input" rows = "4" ></textarea></div >' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';
$('#admin_chatRoom').append(chatBox);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="admin_chatRoom"></div>
```